# For loop update for Swift 2.2 throwing Binary Operator error

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I'm trying to update some of my swift code to comply with the swift 2.2 guide lines. I'm trying to update my for loops this is what I have currently

```
for(var i = 0; persons?.count > i; i += 1){}
```

and this is what I thought I should be using

```
for i in (0..<persons?.count){}
```

But I'm getting this error "Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?'"

I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: what is person here ?

Comment: an array of objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `persons?.count` might be `nil` and `0..<nil` doesn't make any sense. you can easily fix this by using nil coalescing though:

```
for i in 0..<(persons?.count ?? 0) {
    doStuff(i)
}
```

Or if you prefer you could overload the `..<` operator to accept an optional as its second argument:

```
func ..<<T:ForwardIndexType where T:Comparable>(lower: T, upper: T?) -> Range<T> {
    return lower..<(upper ?? lower)
}
```

This allows you to just write:

```
for i in 0..<persons?.count {
    doStuff(i)
}
```

As Sulthan points out in the comments, this is probably not the best solution for your problem though. You should likely handle the case of `persons` being `nil` earlier in your code:

```
guard let persons = persons else {
    // take care of business
}

for person in persons {
    doStuff(person)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clean solution!

Comment: Actually, after having tested the overload, Swift doesn't appear to like it as it's causing an infinite loop (the `..<` is calling itself) due to the type specificness of using `Int` (Swift always favours the more specific signature) and the fact that types can be freely promoted to optionals. You'll have to make it generic instead (i.e `func ..<<T:ForwardIndexType>(lower: T, upper: T?) -> Range<T>`)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @originaluser2, I wish I could give you some rep for this.

Comment: @overactor No problem :)

Comment: Hiding the handling of `nil` behind custom operators is not a good idea. The better solution would probably be to handle the case when `persons` is `nil` much earlier. For arrays, we can use an empty array `[]` instead of `nil` in most cases. The count then will be `0`.